# How to get session data for API requests?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get authorized user data. But instead I get the data of a completely different user.  How to write a function getProfile to display the data of the current user?

controllers/auth.js:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user

module.exports.login = async function(req, res) {
    const candidate = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: req.body.username
        }
    })
    if (candidate) {
        const passwordResult = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, candidate.password)
        if (passwordResult) {
            const token = jwt.sign({
                username: candidate.username,
                userId: candidate._id
            }, process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY, {expiresIn: 60 * 60})

            res.status(200).json({
                token: `Bearer ${token}`
            })
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Passwords do not match. Try again.'
            })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User with this login was not found.'
        })
    }
}

module.exports.getProfile = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({id: req.body.id})
        res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

routes/auth.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const controller = require('../controllers/auth')
const passport = require('passport')

router.post('/login', controller.login)
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), controller.getProfile)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Looking at your current implementation, `getProfile` is dependent on `id` sent  in `req.bdy` and it's not strickly attached with with user loggedIn. He can send whatever id he wants to access their profile.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati How can I connect with the user loggedIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach a signed token in each HTTP req from client, either by custom HTTP header or set in `cookie`. This token is sent only after successful login which contains user's id and other info.

After you start receiving that token you can validate it (checking for expiry or some manual change) using a middleware and that token data will be the actual user data belongs to the user loggedin.

Now, you read that header/cookie to get requester user's info and you can then send their respective data only.

Let's say if client is sending you token info in header called `tkn`. Your token validation can be as follows:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const SECRET = 'whatulike';

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers.tkn || "";
  if (!token.length)
    return unauthorised(res, 'Token absent');
  jwt.verify(token, SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err)
    return unauthorised(res, 'Failed to authenticate token.');
    req.tkn = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
}

function unauthorised(res, msg){
  const sc = 401;
  logger.warn(`${sc} - Unauthorised request ${res.req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(sc).send({msg});
}

module.exports.verifyToken = verifyToken;
```

And at handler side you can read `tkn` data like:

```
module.exports.getProfile = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({id: req.tkn.userId})
    res.status(200).json(user)
  } catch(e) {
    errorHandler(res, e)
  }
}
```